# How to synchronize an e-commerce site and a pharmacy management software?

Tags: plugin-development

Here is my problem.
I have to create an e-commerce store for a pharmacy. The problem is, I don’t know how to synchronize the site and the pharmacy management software so that when a purchase is made on the site, the drug can be automatically removed from the local pharmacy inventory.
I haven’t started yet but I have to do it with wordpress.org
Please; I have a customer in a hurry

Thanks

*********fr**************
Salut à tous! Voici mon problème.
Je dois créer une boutique e-commerce pour une pharmacie. Le problème, c’est que je ne sais pas comment synchroniser le site et le logiciel de gestion de la pharmacie pour que lorsqu’un achat est effectué sur le site, le médicament puisse être automatiquement retiré de l’inventaire de la pharmacie locale.
Je n’ai pas encore commencé mais je dois le faire avec wordpress.org
S’il vous plaît; J’ai un client pressé

Merci

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the pharmacy's inventory management software can be connected to via API of some sort, you will need to write custom scripts which trigger when an order is placed within your WordPress environment.

In case of WooCommerce, read up on the hook [woocommerce_checkout_order_processed](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_checkout_order_processed/) for example.

Probably most important though - read up on the API documentation of your pharmacy's existing software.